# Consume REST API request body (XML) into SAP BO

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects

How can I consume REST API request body (XML) into SAP BO (IDT) or Crystal report for enterprise 2016. (not Designer)

NOTE - we don't want to introduce any WEB SERVICE here as a solution .

Brief: The requirement is to parse a XML received as part of request body in API and use that XML as a source to IDT and generate PDF from that using Crystal Reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it in the real world, but IDT does support raw XML files as a data source.  When creating a new connection, select Generic -> XML Files -> XML File Connector.